# "IndexError: too many indices for array" appearing when creating a train test split

Tags: python, numpy

I am creating a Neural Network and currently I am working on the; `train, test split` section using:

```
import csv
import math
import numpy as np 
import pandas as pd
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense
import datetime
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

X1 = Values[1:16801] #16,800 values

train_size = int(len(X1) * 0.67)
test_size = len(X1) - train_size

train, test = X1[0:train_size,:], X1[train_size:len(X1),:]
print(len(train), len(test))
```

I have 16,800 values for X1 which look like:

```
[0.03454225 0.02062136 0.00186715 ... 0.92857565 0.64930691 0.20325924]
```

My traceback error message is:

```
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-16-8cadae12af2c> in <module>()
     69 test_size = len(X1) - train_size
     70 
---> 71 train, test = X1[0:train_size,:], X1[train_size:len(X1),:]
     72 print(len(train), len(test))
     73 

IndexError: too many indices for array
```

I'm not sure why this could be,If anyone can help, it  would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is because of the below line:

```
train, test = X1[0:train_size,:], X1[train_size:len(X1),:]
```

Here, your data is a one-dimensional array as is evident from the data posted in your question.
But in the above line, you are using subscript for 2nd dimension. In the above line `0:train_size` will select indices 0 to train_size on 1st dimension and `:` will select all the indices on 2nd dimension. But you don't have a 2nd dimension in your data. Below code should work.

```
import csv
import math
import numpy as np 
import pandas as pd
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense
import datetime
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

# 1D array
X1 = Values[1:16801] #16,800 values

train_size = int(len(X1) * 0.67)
test_size = len(X1) - train_size

train, test = X1[0:train_size], X1[train_size:len(X1)]
print(len(train), len(test))
```