# IndexError: too many indices for array when creating a train test split

Tags: python, machine-learning, index-error

I am creating a Neural Network and currently I am working on the; `train, test split` but I am getting the error `IndexError: too many indices for array` My code is:

```
import csv
import math
import numpy as np 
import pandas as pd
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense
import datetime
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

X1 = Values[1:16801] #16,800 values
Y1 = P1[1:16801]#16,800 values

train_size = int(len(X1) * 0.67)
test_size = len(X1) - train_size

train, test = X1[0:train_size,], X1[train_size:len(X1),]
def Data(X1, look_back=1):
     dataX, dataY = [], []
     for i in range(len(X1)-look_back-1):
         a = X1[i:(i+look_back), 0]
         dataX.append(a)
         dataY.append(Y1[i + look_back, 0])
     return numpy.array(dataX), numpy.array(dataY)

look_back = 1
trainX, testX = Data(train, look_back)

testX, testY = Data(test, look_back)

look_back = 1
trainX, testX = Data(train, look_back)

testX, testY = Data(test, look_back)
```

I have 16,800 values for X1 which look like:

```
[0.03454225 0.02062136 0.00186715 ... 0.92857565 0.64930691 0.20325924]
```

And my Y1 data looks like: `[ 2.25226244  1.44078451  0.99174488 ... 12.8397099   9.75722427 7.98525797]`

My traceback error message is:

```
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-11-afedcaa56e0b> in <module>()
     86 
     87 look_back = 1
---> 88 trainX, testX = Data_split(train, look_back)
     89 
     90 testX, testY = Data_split(test, look_back)

<ipython-input-11-afedcaa56e0b> in Data(X1, look_back)
     78     dataX, dataY = [], []
     79     for i in range(len(X1)-look_back-1):
---> 80         a = X1[i:(i+look_back), 0]
     81         dataX.append(a)
     82         dataY.append(Y1[i + look_back, 0])

IndexError: too many indices for array
```

I asked a very similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51311147/indexerror-too-many-indices-for-array-appearing-when-creating-a-train-test-sp/51311346#51311346) previously and got a answer but unfortunately I cannot apply that solution to this error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with the dimension of an array. you are trying to access element with multiple dimensions indexes which don't exist. look at line number 80.

```
 a = X1[i:(i+look_back), 0]   in your case metrics is just single dimention.
```

sample 2d metrics representation (,)

**","** is the reference to the two-dimensional array with row and column but unfortunately, you are having X1 as ndarray.

```
[0.03454225 0.02062136 0.00186715 ... 0.92857565 0.64930691 0.20325924]
```

**Similar problem example:-**

```
>>> np.ndarray(4)
array([2.0e-323, 1.5e-323, 2.0e-323, 1.5e-323])
>>> a[1:2,0]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#38>", line 1, in <module>
    a[1:2,0]
IndexError: too many indices for array
>>> a[1:2]
array([-2.68156159e+154])
>>>
```

Comment: Thank you, I removed the commas highlighted and it has worked